# How do I use QName (python xml.etree.ElementTree?)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree, qnames

I have done a fair amount of reading on QName but I can't find any good examples of how to use it.  Could someone give me a simple example of how to use QName and explain what context it would be used in?

Answer (score 17):

`QName` can be used when constructing XML documents with attributes that are in a different namespace than the containing element. Example (Python 2.7):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

NS1 = "http://example1.com" 
NS2 = "http://example2.com"

ET.register_namespace("x", NS1) 
ET.register_namespace("y", NS2)

qname1 = ET.QName(NS1, "root")    # Element QName 
qname2 = ET.QName(NS2, "attr")    # Attribute QName

root = ET.Element(qname1, {qname2: "test"}) 
print ET.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<x:root xmlns:x="http://example1.com" xmlns:y="http://example2.com" y:attr="test" />
```

One application for which this can be useful is [XLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLink).

Comment: More examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46405690/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58642263/407651