# How to set namespace for attributes in xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I want to set namespace for attribute in ElementTree to get following result.

```
<test xmlns:ns="test"><test1 ns:name="item1" /></test>
```

I already registered namespaces. But, How should I change the following?

```
test1 = ET.SubElement(test, "test1", name="item1")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678592/407651

Answer (score 0):

You have to `.set()` the attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test xmlns:ns="test">
<test1 ns:name="item1" />
</test>"""

test = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
ET.register_namespace("ns","test")

test2 = ET.SubElement(test, "test2").set('{test}name', 'item2')

ET.indent(test, space = '  ')
ET.dump(test)
```

Output:

```
<test xmlns:ns="test">
  <test1 ns:name="item1" />
  <test2 ns:name="item2" />
</test>
```