# set xsi:schemaLocation attribute when saving xml file with lxml

Tags: python, namespaces, elementtree, xsi

I'm using lxml to write xml file.
I try to write a root element like :

```
<Retour xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.cnamts.fr/cereus/fichier/retour/v1"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cnamts.fr/cereus/fichier/retour/v1retour.xsd">
```

So I try :

```
NSMAP = {"xsi" : 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
retour = ET.Element('Retour', nsmap = NSMAP)
retour.set('xmlns','http://www.cnamts.fr/cereus/fichier/retour/v1')
```

And I got :

```
<Retour xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.cnamts.fr/cereus/fichier/retour/v1">
```

But I don't find how to set `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cnamts.fr/cereus/fichier/retour/v1retour.xsd"`? With `Element.set` I have an unicode error.

Comment: Use `QName` to add `xsi:schemaLocation='...'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422793/407651

Comment: Other similar answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678592/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31074030/407651

Comment: Thanks @mzjn for your help. I did not find this thread which helps me.